# Argument is incompatible with prototype: struct in_addr

Tags: c

I am trying to print some output in my C program.

When I compile with cc, I get this error:

> "whoisclient.c", line 70: argument #1 is incompatible with prototype:
>     prototype: struct in_addr {union  {..} S_un} :
>   "/usr/include/arpa/inet.h", line 61   argument : pointer to char

At this part of my code:

```
 printf("Addresses\n");
      int j=0;
      while(hp ->h_addr_list[j]!=NULL){
        printf("hp_addr_list[%d] = %s\n", j, inet_ntoa(hp->h_addr_list[j]));
        j++;
      }
```

I have tried adding an asterisk or adding / removing `hp->` but I am out of ideas. I don't fully understand the error message and what it is saying I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why aren't you using `getaddrinfo`?

Comment: can you mark line #70 and line #61 on your question please.

Comment: `h_aliases[i]` is also used uninitialized. (should be `while(hp->h_aliases[i]!=NULL)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You're right! Thanks.

Comment: the prototype for `inet_ntoa()` is `char *inet_ntoa(struct in_addr in);`  Notice the parameter is a instance of a struct.  (that instance only contains a `uint32_t` field, however, must pass the instance of a the struct,  You have not shown us the rest of your code, so we cannot determine exactly what you have done wrong.

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `inet_ntoa` function takes a `struct in_addr`, which contains a numerical representation of an IPv4 address, and returns a pointer to a string contains a text representation of that IP address.

The `h_addr_list` field of a `struct hostent` is a pointer to an array of pointers to strings, each of which contains an IPv4 address.  This is incompatible with what `inet_ntoa` is expecting.

Since you already have a string representation of an IP address and not a numerical representation, you don't need to pass it through `inet_ntoa` to convert it.  Just pass the string directly to `printf`:

```
printf("hp_addr_list[%d] = %s\n", j, hp->h_addr_list[j]);
```

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments, the `h_addr_list` member, which is defined as type `char **` is actually an array of pointers to network addresses in network byte order.  Such an element is the same as the contents of a `struct in_addr`.  So the `char *` needs to be casted to a `struct in_addr *` and then dereferenced:

```
printf("hp_addr_list[%d] = %s\n", j, inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)hp->h_addr_list[j])));
```

Comment: You write quicker than I. Good job. (you may also look things up a bit quicker too `:)`

Comment: A little deeper digging may show `hp->h_addr_list[j]` is in *network-byte-order*, to actually output it as a character string, you will end up with `printf("hp_addr_list[%d] = %s\n", j, inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)hp->h_addr_list[j]));`